# create dynamic multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create dynamic multidimensional array using PHP

I need to generate array like this ...

```
$fetchMenu = array('page-1' => array(
'name' => 'first_page',
'label' => 'First page 2',
'route' => 'product_index',
'pages' => array(
array(
'name' => 'xxx',
'label' => 'xxx',
'route' => 'product_index',
), array(
'id' => 'permissions',
'label' => 'Permissions',
'title' => 'Permissions',
'route' => 'product_add',
'menu_tree_path' => 'default|system|roles_and_permission|permissions',
'display_in_menu' => true,
)
),
),
'page-2' => array(
'name' => 'second_page',
'label' => 'Second page 2',
'route' => 'product_index',
'pages' => array(),
),);
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?...please post that code as well

Comment: What do you want to dynamically add? There's many ways to do this, it all depends on what you want. Also, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I am working to generate zend framework 2 navigation dynamically. I was able to add main menu and sub pages. I need some ideas to secondary, third level sub menus.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$dynMenu = array();
$bookLength = 5; //function getBookLength() ??
for($i=0;$i<$bookLength;$i++){
  $pageNumber = 'page'.$i;
  $page = $i; // function getPages() ??
  $dynMenu[$pageNumber] = array('name' => 'foo', 'label' => 'bar');
  for($j=0;$j<$page;$j++){
    $dynMenu[$pageNumber][$j] = array('name' => 'foo-ish', 'label' => 'bar-ish');
  }
}
```